# Map reduce to count tags

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am developing a web app using Codeigniter and MongoDB.
I am trying to get the map reduce to work.

I got a file document with the below structure. I would like to do a map reduce to
check how many times each tag is being used and output it to the collection files.tags.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$id": "4f26f21f09ab66c1030d0000e"
    },
    "basic": {
        "name": "The filename"
    },
    "tags": [
        "lorry",
        "house",
        "car",
        "bicycle"
    ],
    "updated_at": "2012-02-09 11:08:03"
}
```

I tried this map reduce command but it does not count each individual tag:

```
$map = new MongoCode ("function() {

 emit({tags: this.tags}, {count: 1});

}");

    $reduce = new MongoCode ("function( key , values ) {

     var count = 0;

     values.forEach(function(v) {
      count += v['count'];
     });

     return {count: count};

    }");

    $this->mongo_db->command (array (

     "mapreduce" => "files",   
     "map"       => $map,   
     "reduce"    => $reduce,   
     "out"       => "files.tags"

    )

    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, this map/reduce simply calculate total count of tags.

In mongodb cookbook [there is example](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/count_tags/) you are looking for.

You have to emit each tag instead of entire collection of tags:

```
map = function() {
    if (!this.tags) {
        return;
    }

    for (index in this.tags) {
        emit(this.tags[index], 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked fine! Right now each document in files.tags gets _id of from the tag name. I would like to give each document a normal MongoId and then add tag: 'thetag' to the each document instead. How can I do that?

Comment: @JonathanClark: from my practice map reduce is always slow, and i am trying to avoid it. Or if it really needed i moving it to background async process or use [incremental](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-MongoShellScriptwithIncrementalMapReduceandFinalize) map/reduce that is faster because it operate with not full data source. So in general map/reduce is not acceptable for real time calculations, especially with big volumes of data.

Comment: Yeah, that is sad. Do you know how to use normal MongoIds instead of setting the _id to the tag name? And add the tag name to the document instead?

Comment: I am not sure if it possible generate `ObjectId` within map/reduce. If you wanna have tag name within value you can `emit (this.tags[index], {tag: this.tags[index], count: 1})` and change your reduce function according to this. And if tags array will have unique `ObjectId` you can send id instead of tag name into reduce func as key.

Comment: How should the reduce step look like now?

Answer (score 2):

Change your Map function to:

```
function map(){
  if(!this.tags) return;
  this.tags.forEach(function(tag){
      emit(tag, {count: 1});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to call emit once for each tag in the input documents.

MongoDB documentation for example says:

> A map function calls emit(key,value) any
>   number of times to feed data to the reducer. In most cases you will
>   emit once per input document, but in some cases such as counting tags,
>   a given document may have one, many, or even zero tags.

Comment: If I got 1.000.000 documents in the file collection with 5 tags for each will Map reduce still be quick?

Comment: it will probably take around 10 minutes I believe. What do you define as quick?

Comment: Ah ok. I just wanted to get a feel for it. Perhaps it is better to update the tag count when a user creates a new file document?